# youtube library initialization error in youtube API

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to play an youtube video in my Android app. I created the new API and downloaded the Jar file then added it in the libs folder. finally did a sync.

```
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```

Then i added the layout

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

in the java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promo);  

    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, promo.this);

 }

     @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if (!b) {

        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {

         youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(promo.this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
    } else {

      String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        Toast.makeText(promo.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, promo.this);
    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return youTubeView;
}
```

also added the internet permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using the appropriate type of [library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) required. You may follow the sample code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33832933/5832311) and [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/handle-initialization-error-youtube-api.html).